# How to convert factors to date format

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

```
Id.      Int.   Date.                 
234.     10.    10-05-2018
345.     05.    15-05-2018
564.     04.    17-06-2018

DF <- read.csv(file)
str(df)
```

I found date is in factor, so I want another column next to Date column with those date but in date format.

```
df$dte <- as.Date(df$Date, format= "%d/%b/%Y")
```

But I got a column next to Date called "date"column but the values are `<NA>`.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Your format is not specified correctly. `%b` is the text representation of month in your locale - e.g. Jan, Feb etc, not the numeric month. See `?strptime`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `df$dte <- as.Date(df$Date, format= "%d/%b/%Y")` to `df$dte <- as.Date(df$Date, format= "%d-%m-%Y")` .